# What is the meaning of Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: )

Tags: ios, swift, string, indexing

I am trying to understand what does `_rawBits` really mean in `Swift.String.Index(_rawBits:)`. If you print a `String.Index`, you get something like `Swift.String.Index(_rawBits: 983040)`. But what does that really mean?

Can I (mathematically) calculate the actual index in a string using this rawBits number at all? either base 32, 16, or whatever else?

Swift `Range` uses `String.Index` as its upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 3):

> Swift `Range` uses `String.Index` as its upper and lower bounds.`

No, it doesn't. `Range<String.Index>` does, but that's only one particular type of `Range`, which is otherwise generic over a type variable called `Bound`.

The `_rawBits` are an internal implementation detail of the string indices. You should treat them as an opaque type, that you can only manipulate using the corresponding index apis on `String`, `Substring` and friends.

Comment: In general, types and method signatures that begin with underscores are private/internal to Apple's frameworks, and you should ignore them and follow the documentation.

Comment: @DuncanC The strange part is that the bits are exposed by the implementation of `String.Index.description`. I guess it's useful for visually identifying one index, and seeing if it's distinct from another, but it's still leaking that implementation detail

Comment: This was really common in Objective-C with it runtime binding. Often Objective C classes were actually implemented by private subclasses like `_NSStaticString`